# Kafka Closing socket connection due to invalid request

Tags: apache-kafka

I have searched solution for this question but couldn't find good answer so posting my scenario & solution which I solved.

Closing socket connection due to invalid request: Request of length is not valid, it is larger than the maximum size of bytes

Answer (score 0):

**Solution: 1**
    You will get this error if your producer batch size & sum(each message size) > socket.request.max.bytes

Optimal configuration:
    Give same value for all the below properties

1. socket.send.buffer.bytes
2. socket.receive.buffer.bytes
3. socket.request.max.bytes (Important! 1 max message size * batch size)
4. message.max.bytes
5. replica.fetch.max.bytes

**Solution: 2**
    Use same encoder in both producer client & in Kafka. I am using default encoder. Eg. serializer.class=kafka.serializer.DefaultEncoder